# Creating a wedge shape with Geotools

Tags: java, gis, geotools

I am on the hook for creating a service which will create a shape based on data provided with a center point.  I am working with geotools which I am not very experienced with, however I am getting more familiar with it.

I am receiving data which looks like this:

```
{
    "shape": {
    "latitude": 43.87,
    "longitude": -103.45,
    "parameters": [
        0.0,
        120.0,
        1000.0
    ],
    "shapeString": "WEDGE (-103.45,43.87) AZIMUTH:0.0 ANGLE:120.0 RADIUS:1000.0"
  }
}
```

I am assuming there is a way to create this shape in geotools but I am just so unfamiliar with it I haven't been able to do it. I have seen the ability to create polygons, however it looks like I would have to have several sets of lat,lon to create that type of shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [program](https://gist.github.com/ianturton/40c3ed7816859fa3dde1300b94bc2334) to solve a similar problem some time ago.

Basically, the trick is to use the `GeodeticCalculator` to work out the coordinates of the curved section of the wedge and the join the start and end to the starting point.

```
ArrayList<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<>();
// start at the tower
coords.add(point.getCoordinate());
// next the edge of the wedge
int nSteps = 10;
// assume width of 10 degrees
double width = 10.0;
double dStep = width/nSteps;
for (int i = -nSteps; i < nSteps; i++) {
  CALC.setStartingGeographicPoint(point.getX(), point.getY());
  CALC.setDirection((azimuth +(i*dStep)), radius);
  Point2D p = CALC.getDestinationGeographicPoint();
  coords.add(new Coordinate(p.getX(), p.getY()));
}
// end at the tower
coords.add(point.getCoordinate());
poly = GF.createPolygon(coords.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
```